# When is $f=f^{-1}$ for $f(x)=x^3+14x-14$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The function $f(x)=x^3+14x−14$ is a monotonically increasing function, hence it is injective (one-to-one), so its inverse function exists and is well defined. How many points of intersection are there between the function $f(x)$ and its inverse $f^{−1}(x)$?

Answer (score 7):

If a function intersects its inverse at some point, then it intersects this inverse on the line $y=x$ (caveat: this excludes functions which are their own inverse).

$$ x = x^3 + 14x - 14 $$
$$ 0 = x^3 + 13x - 14 $$

Factoring gives us:

$$ 0 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 14) $$

So either $x - 1 = 0$, or $x^2 + x + 14 = 0$ (not possible). Hence, $x = 1$, and there is one intersection between the function and its inverse.

Answer (score 3):

This should prove easier with calculus. First, note that $f(1)=1$; so $f(x)$ meets $y=x$ on $x=1$. Look at the derivative $$f'(x)=2x^2+14$$

It is always positive. Since it's minimum value is on $x=0$, and is $=14>1$ ($1$ is the slope of $y=x$), $f$ cannot intersect with $y=x$ again (since it goes away faster than $y=14x$). But if $f=f^{-1}$, it is on a point on $y=x$. This means the only point of intersection is $x=1$.